# UWP change thumbnail of a StorageFile

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I am relying on a button click to change the thumbnail of a `StorageFile`. (It is a music file.)

And I want to achieve that by choosing an image file from the local.

```
    private async void ChangeAlbumArtButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var music_file = await CurrentMusic.GetStorageFileAsync();
        using (var dst = await music_file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 1024))
        {
            if (!dst.CanWrite)
            {
                MainPage.Instance.ShowNotification(Helper.LocalizeMessage("UnableToChangeAlbumArt"));
                return;
            }
            FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker
            {
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
            };
            foreach (var item in new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" })
                picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(item);
            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file == null) return;
            using (var src_stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                await dst.WriteAsync(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file));
                var src = new BitmapImage();
                src.SetSource(src_stream);
                AlbumArt.Source = src;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, `dst.CanWrite` is false. How should change the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a third party library called TagLib to solve my problem:

```
using (var tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(new MusicFileAbstraction(await CurrentMusic.GetStorageFileAsync()), ReadStyle.Average))
{
    FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker
    {
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    };
    foreach (var item in new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg", ".mp3" })
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(item);
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file == null) return;
    if (FolderTree.IsMusicFile(file))
    {
        using (var source = TagLib.File.Create(new MusicFileAbstraction(file), ReadStyle.Average))
        {
            if (source.Tag.Pictures.Length == 0)
            {
                MainPage.Instance.ShowNotification(Helper.LocalizeMessage("MusicNoAlbumArt", file.DisplayName));
                return;
            }
            tagFile.Tag.Pictures = source.Tag.Pictures;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tagFile.Tag.Pictures = new Picture[] { new Picture(new MusicFileAbstraction(file)) { Type = PictureType.BackCover } };
    }
    AlbumArt.Source = await BytesToBitmapImage(tagFile.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.ToArray());
    AlbumArt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    tagFile.Save();
}
```

I basically allow user to open an image file from the local or copy the album art from a music file. Then you create a Picture object or read those album arts from the music file, then assign it to the target music file.

Notice the use of `MusicFileAbstraction`. Without that you will get `UnauthorizedAccessException`. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/MusicHelper.cs).

More source code can be found [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/AlbumArtControl.xaml.cs).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to change the thumbnail of the file, this is not a way to write the stream by code.

The provider of the thumbnail is the default application for opening the file. For example, the default application for opening a music file is `Groove Music`, and the thumbnail you see is provided by `Groove Music`.

If you plan to modify the thumbnail of the music file,

- First, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation) to set up the file association protocol, add the music file to the associated list, and provide an image file.
- Then set your app to the default app for opening music files.

---

If you are not planning to establish a file type association. there is an easy way, you can use the image file instead of `GetThumbnailAsync()` method, that means, do not get the thumbnail, directly display the selected image on the UI.

Best regards.

Comment: Actually thumbnail is not provided by Groove. It is an attribute of a music file (Notice the `Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.MusicView` I used in the parameter). You can download a music file from a platform like qq music. You can see its thumbnail is read as the album cover not the groove icon shown in Windows.

Comment: So what you want to do is modify the album cover of the music file?

Comment: I would say yes (because the thumbnail happens to be the same as the album cover) and I am doing it by changing the `StorageItemThumbnail`. I don't know if there is another way to change it.

Comment: I did more experiments, including modifying Meta-Data for music files, but that didn't work. Currently UWP does not provide a method to modify the album cover of music files. You can find some related third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can access files directly from System Drive.

### 1.StorageItemAccessList

If all your files are going to be in one folder the you can use `StorageItemAccessList` to get hold of a folder Which **user picks** and you can access it anytime you want

You can have look at the example from Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist#examples)

### 2.BroadFileSystemAccess

If you need complete access to all the folder then you need `BroadFileSystemAccess`. it's restricted capability which will help you access files fromanywhere.

Have a look about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)